# Value cannot be null parameter name second

Tags: c#

I have the following code. Here the `newList` is `null` because of which I am getting an error. How can I prevent this.

```
combinedList = (combinedList ?? new List<combinedList>()).Concat(newList).ToList();
```

Which is returning me the following error.

> 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: second'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `??` again:

```
combinedList = (combinedList ?? new List<combinedList>())
    .Concat(newList ?? new List<combinedList>())
    .ToList();
```

Though it seems like you really just want this:

```
combinedList ??= new List<combinedList>();
if (newList != null)
{
    combinedList.AddRange(newList);
}
```